# x509 certificates in a secured connection

Tags: php, ssl, encryption, x509

What is the meaning of `RSA PRIVATE KEY` and `PUBLIC KEY` that a `x509` certificate contains?

UPD: @owlstead: I tried out [phpseclib](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/new/x509/tutorial.html):

```
$text = "test"; 
$x509 = new File_X509();
$cert = $x509->loadX509(file_get_contents(CERT_PATH.'root.crt'));
$Crypt_RSA = $x509->getPublicKey();
extract($Crypt_RSA->createKey()); // got $publickey and $privatekey
$Crypt_RSA->loadKey($publickey);
$crypted_text = $Crypt_RSA->encrypt($text);
$Crypt_RSA->loadKey($privatekey);
$decrypted_text = $Crypt_RSA->decrypt($ciphertext);
```

Comment: It isn't anything even slightly like that. I suggest you look up SSL and PKI, instead of just making it up. There's not much point in commenting in detail on stray guesswork.

Comment: I thought so and it is embarassing, so I edited question, is it answerable?

Comment: [This](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5280#section-4) is an X509 certificate. And [this](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5246) is modern TLS (aka SSL). You haven't really asked a question yet.

Comment: @owlstead: any certificate actually does have `PUBLIC KEY` and `RSA PRIVATE KEY` and that's what confused me.

Comment: OK, congratulations, you salvaged your question :)

Comment: No, any certificate actually does *not* contain a private key. You are mistaken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`createKey()` creates a new key pair, i.e. a public and private key that do *not* belong to any certificate yet.

Comment: the message encrypted by `public key` on one host can be decrypted by `private key` on other host, and the **same** certificate is used. Can you please explain me the difference? And moreover, my question is about the right usage of certificates - two-sided secure communication of my server and other hosts (I want to control the validity period of host certificates)

Comment: @zogby A certificate is a wrapper around a public key. I don't know what you mean by 'the same certificate is used'. A certificate doesn't even need to exist for public-key cryptography to work at the lowest level.

Comment: The certificate is used to establish trust in the public key that is part of the certificate. This is done by validating the certificate chain to a trusted certificate. The message is then encrypted by the public key and decrypted with the private key of the party that received the certificate for his public/private key pair. This is called PKI, and it is probably best to read a book about it first, it cannot be contained in a single answer.

Comment: @EJP If it is a wrapper for public key how does it deal with `RSA PRIVATE KEY`?

Comment: I think you wanted to comment on EJP at your question not at my answer. The certificate does not deal with RSA PRIVATE KEY. A new one was created when you called `createKey` as explained in my answer.

Comment: @zogby It *doesn't* 'deal with the private key'. There is no private key in a certificate. A certificate is a public document attesting that this person owns this public key and the private key that goes with it, but the private key is, err, private. Putting it into the certificate would be somewhat counter-productive. You didn't mention anything about validity periods in your actual question. I suggest you clarify it. Again.

Comment: @owlstead Perfect, I got it, so, I create my CA certificate out of my secret generated **private key** and add it to every host's **trusted root certificate authorities**. Then I receive a **request** for a certificate from that host and sign it with my **private key**, defining the valid period. And I guess it's fine when I make a request to host (his certificate is validated by my CA, which is trusted), but what happens when he requests me?

Comment: You need some other method of establishing trust. I.e. browsers use their certificate cache shipped with the browser, web-CA's simply check if the name of your web address is correct, you can use a personal connection etc. etc. etc. YOu cannot establish trust to somebody without any additional information.

Comment: @zogby No again. You create a certificate from a *public* key. The only relationship between a certificate and a private key is via the public key.

Comment: @EJP (from [openssl HOWTO certificates](https://www.openssl.org/docs/HOWTO/certificates.txt))
    `...The rest of this text assumes you have a private key in the file privkey.pem...
    4. Creating a self-signed test certificate
    ...
    openssl req -new -x509 -key privkey.pem -out cacert.pem -days 1095`

Comment: @zogby It also says 'Certificates are related to public key cryptography by containing a public key. To be useful, there must be a corresponding private key somewhere.'

Comment: @EJP Yes, it is related and it is containing, but it is derived form private key, right?